# Command \textdiscount unavailable in encoding OT1. ...ton exchange membranes and 10\textdiscount

Tags: errors

Can anyone please solve the above error, I want to represent 10% in my paper. I used 10\textdiscount, 10$\textdiscount$, $10\textdiscount$. everything leads me to the above error. can anyone please tell me the solution. I also want to represent $10.. \textdollar also not working. please help me to solve this.

Comment: What about `10\%` and `\$10`?

Answer (score 1):

If I compile

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\textdiscount\textdollar

\end{document}
```

I get

```
> pdflatex discount
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./discount.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./discount.aux
)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \textdiscount
                 \textdollar
? 
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./discount.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfon
ts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on discount.pdf (1 page, 8924 bytes).
Transcript written on discount.log.
```

and there's a “$” in the output.

There *is* `\textdiscount` if you load the `textcomp` package, but it's for a funny symbol that's not the standard one for percentages.

Type, much more simply,

```
I'll let you pay just \$80, which means a discount by 10\%.
```